# What is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/json and why do I need it?

Tags: python, pip, artifactory

I configured Python3 installation for artifactory, since mine servers are beyond firewall and there is no chance for me to reach pypi.python.org. Installation of packages "succeeds" but at the end I get error:

```
...
Cleaning up...
Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/json" in the cache
No cache entry available
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
There was an error checking the latest version of pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 142, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 98, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 88, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

I configured pip3 to use artifactory, it works I can access packages, but the installation is not 100% correct.

```
$ cat ~/.pip/pip.conf
[global]
index-url = https://artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-remote/simple

[index]
index-url = https://artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-remote/simple
```

Is there something more to configure? Or is it a pip bug?
I use pip 9.0.1 from RHEL7 SCL installation

Comment: There is no command `pip index`: `[index]` should be `[install]`, I think.

Comment: It's the version check. By default, `pip` always tries to compare the installed version with the latest available on PyPI and issues a warning if the local one is outdated. You can disable version checking behaviour by appending the option `--disable-pip-version-check` to install command, or persist it in the `pip.conf` to not having to enter it each time: `disable_pip_version_check=1`.

Comment: Also, judging by the used host (`pypi.python.org`), it looks like you've got an older `pip` installed (earlier than version 10?). IIRC old versions didn't honor `index-url` for version checking, neither from command line nor from config and fetched from PyPI regardless; this was changed in version 10. So even if your custom PyPI repo proxies the requests to PyPI, it won't help since `pip` will never use it for version checking. So if you can download the latest `pip` wheel and update the package locally, you may not even need the version check disabling.